# Why are the MythVideo settings blank in the frontend in MythTV 0.22 and later?

Tags: mythtv, mythbuntu

In the MythTV 0.22 frontend, why are the default settings blank? Why are these not populated to the correct content directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MythTV 0.22 introduces Storage Groups for MythVideo. These are setup by default for you in mythtv-setup, and will conflict with the local frontend settings if the paths are the same. Local MythVideo settings will not use the MythTV protocol to transfer videos between your frontends. See [MythVideo - Local Video Storage](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/MythVideo#Local_Video_Storage)